# How to solve inequalities, algorithmically?

Tags: inequality, algorithms

I'm working on a project of my own, I'm making a programming language; I want to introduce quite good capabilities for it for comparisons, however I admit math was not my best subject, so the question is very simple

given a comparison where I compare a value x with another y, whose can be of any mathematical type, being number, function (includes cos, log, etc...) how do I know for certain whether it is true, false or I can't determine it.

eg.

```
x > 7      (?)
k*2 > y      (?)
x <= 2x     (true)
x < 2xy    (?)
x/2 > x^2  (false)
cos(x) > 2 (true)
2*PI > 3.14 (true)
```

I'm pretty sure there must be a method whose process is implemented somewhere that I could just use in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought: Some of these will depend on what $x$ is; for example, if $0 < x < 1$, then you have $x > x^2$, but for $x > 1$ the inequality reverses: $x < x^2$. Another quick example, for $0 < a < b$, we have $1/a > 1/b$; but if all you know is $a < b$, then you cannot come to such a conclusion, for it might be that $a < 0 < b$, in which case $1/a < 1/b$.

Comment: $cos(x)$ max value is 1

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without some more information about what you are trying to do in your programming language. Are you trying to assign truth values to arithmetic relations like $x < 2x$ during program execution before you have evaluated $x$ (as you might in some constraint programming approaches)? Or what?

Comment: @RobArthan yes in fact, it works pretty much like a CAS meaning that it has not been evaluated, x is just "something".

Comment: Not just truth but also an no determination result, in case it can't be known for certain like $x > y$ you could never tell

Comment: you could use differentiation to solve intervals for many of these inequations. depending on your programming skills you can either try and make it symbolic or numeric.

Comment: @Onza: in that case, I'm afraid you need to learn a great deal about computer algebra and computational logic.

Comment: @mathreadler the entire system is completely made out of symbolic objects, they already do a lot at organizing their state, I can transform them and manipulate them as required, the main issue is that I don't want to come with a random solution giving that I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'm certain others have tackled this issue before and I can just use their design.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own implementation of a numerical equation solving technique. You can start with something simple like a binary subdivision. It works like this:

Let us assume the function is $f(x) = left(x) - right(x)$

1. Find two points $x_0,x_1$, $\cases{f(x_0) < 0\\f(x_1) > 0}$ or $\cases{f(x_0) > 0\\f(x_1) < 0}$.
2. Now check the middle point $\frac{x_0+x_1}{2}$, is it positive or negative?
3. Replace the previous of $x_0$ and $x_1$ (whichever had the same sign).
4. Repeat!

You will now systematically shrink the interval by half each round you do this so you will be getting better and better approximations to where $f$ switches sign.

Comment: There is no point refining the root once you have established it exist !

Comment: @YvesDaoust If the program is supposed to find for which sets of $x$ a given inequation holds it seems to me to be a reasonable functionality to be able to refine the precision of those boundaries.

Comment: In the OP, only a  boolean result is mentioned (though I agree that this is a poor requirement). Also, your answer seems to mean that a single point suffices.

Comment: The statement "find two points $x_0,x_1$..." looks like an innocuous operation, but this is the crux of the question, and in the general case you are practically helpless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You and I could probably challenge each other in creating one more devious function than the other where that would be increasingly difficult. But why kill the happiness and eagerness of someone wanting to learn mathematics and related algorithms? What good would it do? Is this not a site for encouraging people to learn?

Comment: What method would you advise to find $x_0,x_1$ ?

Comment: Usually one knows roughly what $x$s one is interested in. It would probably be clear from context of the application and could be an input to the function or the purpose of another function to figure out given a context encoded somehow. But that is not the point of my argument. The point is not to discourage people in advance but let them try and see the difficulties for themselves.

Comment: In a symbolic context, you don't have rough ranges. The point is that believing this to be an easy and solved problem is illusory.

Comment: Many things in life are not easy. But they don't get any easier if getting discouraged and giving up before even getting started learning.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

For general expressions, this is not possible. (For just polynomial expressions, this is arduous and must be done numerically.)

Comment: Well sagemath does it somehow and so many CAS out there, I'm just hoping to know the algorithm or some method that is available to read or understand to apply in my problem; many of the CAS just do too much for me to even attempt to follow their processes.

Comment: There are two cases: if you want to solve symbolically, only a few special cases are on hand. If you want to solve numerically, there is no bulletproof method available for root isolation.

Comment: I'm using symbolic computation, otherwise  it'd have been a simple one; the problem is that I don't know which or what methods to apply but I'm certain there has to be a paper or procedure somewhere.

Comment: "I'm using symbolic computation, otherwise it'd have been a simple one": not at all ! And I was mentioning both symbolic and numerical methods to be used in the frame of a symbolic system (because in many cases solutions don't have a closed-form).

Comment: Yves is right that this is a very difficult problem *in general*. But he is wrong in saying so in the sense that many methods are *good enough in practice* for lots of applications and lots of practically reasonably well behaved functions where one can give bounds of the $x$s of interest.

Comment: @mathreadler: can you name one ?